# Extending Python lightblue module to use multiple bluetooth dongles

Tags: python, bluetooth, programming

I'm using the lightblue module and pybluez to send files via bluetooth to obex protocol object push. But I need to use multiple bluetooth dongles (3 and more) to send files to multiple devices (20 and more) at the same time.

I need to tell lightblue to use a specific hcix and use it to connect and send. Can I edit the lightblue module so that it can support this feature?

[this is the source file](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/lightblue/lightblue-0.4.tar.gz?download)

At the end of the source (`_lightblue.py`)

```
# Gets HCI socket thru PyBluez. Remember to close the returned socket.
def _gethcisock(devid=-1):
    try:
        sock = bluetooth.bluez._gethcisock(devid)
    except Exception, e:
        raise _lightbluecommon.BluetoothError(
            "Cannot access local device: " + str(e))
    return sock
```

I can send a specific ID for this method, but lightblue won't use this sock to connect and send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, lightblue internally uses the PyBluez library, which doesn't currently allow a socket to opened on a specific HCI device. PyBluez internally uses the Linux bluetooth sockets functionality, so it depends on whether that allows sockets to be created for a specific HCI device. My guess is that it doesn't, else this functionality would have been exposed in the PyBluez API, but it would be worth checking. If it's possible, then obviously PyBluez and lightblue could be changed to allow as well.